# Bootstrap Placing one image over another?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a col-md-3 on my page and I have placed a .png picture and table inside. I have made the picture on 2 parts and I would like to make the 1st picture rotate, but I can't position the 2 pictures one over another.
When I try to position them above the table, they are one after another or over the table, or when I re-size the page, they don't look like they are supposed to be.
Currently the 1st picture is above the second.

Is there any suggestion how can I position them? Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/other/sch1.png">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/other/sch2.png">
    <table id="contesttable" class="table" style="text-align: center;">
    ..........
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the broken script tag ??

Comment: you can use `carousel` for the `image`.

Comment: could you give me some example of how it's going to work in the current code?

Comment: The script tag is for a button it doesn't affect the pictures. I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: what is the question? do you want to overlay images?

Comment: have you ever heard of `position absolute` and `z-index`?!

Comment: The first Picture is a circle and the secound one is a ring. The 2th picture(the ring) has to be over the 1st(the circle) so I can make the 2th rotate. How do I position them?
Thats the Question.

Comment: I tryed to position them absolute and using z-index but then the table goes over them @Alex

Comment: @StillMoJo this is basic css....

Comment: I am not getting the positioning I want with your suggestion
" -have you ever heard of position absolute and z-index?! –  @Alex

Comment: with postion absolute and z-index the table moves up and goes under the pictures.

Comment: @StillMoJo I didnt say just typing position and z-index will result in your final css. have you ever written some css yourself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87464/discussion-between-stillmojo-and-alex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: (style="position:absolute;")

```
    <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 50px;">
                    <img class="img-responsive"  style="position:absolute;" src="img/other/sch1.png">
                    <img class="img-responsive"  style="position:absolute;" src="img/other/sch2.png">
                    <table id="contesttable" class="table" style="text-align: center;">
                        ..........
                    </table>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oLo2psLn/[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/oLo2psLn/)

you can then use in your styles: z-index:1; or z-index:2;
this will select which image goes on top, higher value goes on top: so 2 on top of 1.